# Character encoding in region list

Tags: magento-1.8, character-encoding, regions, countries

I've just imported a big list of regions/states to the Magento table **directory_country_region** as UTF8

However, in the region/state box at checkout I now see encoding issues for many special characters. As this droplist is not the only place where this information is printed out I need to find a solution that work sitewide.
Is there like any global setting that can sort this?

Comment: This is how my Magento DB looks like:  
character_set_client,utf8  
character_set_connection,utf8  
character_set_database,latin1  
character_set_filesystem,binary  
character_set_results,utf8  
character_set_server,latin1  
character_set_system,utf8  
character_sets_dir,/usr/share/mysql/charsets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleteted everything and reimported with Latin 1 as I noted that: 
**character_set_database, latin1**

Looks good at checkout so hopefully this will work.

For those of you interested I used this post of how to make the import:
http://www.techawaken.com/adding-region-states-options-dropdown-address-checkout-pages/

As for the data I exported everthing from an different platform in Magento format and excluded all countries currently in the table **directory_country_region**